# How to direct connect two virtual machine's NICs on vmware player?

Tags: virtual-machines

I have two virtual machine on vmware player both, each have a NIC card. I want to direct connect VM1's NIC to VM2's NIC, not bridge, not NAT, not Host-only, just direct connect like connect through wire.

Is is possible? How can I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In network settings you can choose a separate Virtual Machine Network to connect them to.
However if you want full control on how this network acts you need Workstation.

But in the end, the closest you'll get is the two vm's in one network without dhcp (but a straight cable connection is nothing different).

Comment: I have tested the solution, there seem be a virtual switch in the network which the two cables connected. But they aren't direct connected still. I run `tcpreplay` to send packets on VM1, and VM2 doesn't recive the packets.

Comment: I make a mistake. Just use `sar` and `ifstat` to count the recived packets which sended by `tcpreplay` on another vm, they show nothing. I use `tcpdump` instead, then I got the right answer.